# Map.setAll instead of multiple map.set calls

Tags: javascript, performance, dictionary, set

With `map.set(key, value)` you can add (or overwrite) a value for a specific key in the map.

If you have a big list of key-value pairs you need to add them all to the list separately:

```
[['keyA', 'valueA'],
 ['keyB', 'valueB'],
 ['keyC', 'valueC']].forEach(pair => map.set(...pair))
```

This does not look very performant as it involves a lot function calls.

**Is there a faster way to do this?**

Comment: The `map` already may have items in it, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could take the array directly for a new [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instance.

```js
var keyValues = [['keyA', 'valueA'], ['keyB', 'valueB'], ['keyC', 'valueC']],
    map = new Map(keyValues);

console.log([...map]);
```

Comment: Only works if the original `map` is empty, which doesn't seem known yet

Comment: right, otherwise you need for every pair a new call of `set`.